# How to get back old existing version ipa file from itunesconnect?

Tags: ios

Already my application is on App Store **(Version 1.5.1)** with PayPal payment SDK. And recently i updated new features and i resubmit **(version 1.5.2)**. But there were some issues are occur like (PayPal SDK not working & some functional issues are also available). I need to remove **Version 1.5.2** version from Appstore and i need to continue old **version 1.5.1** only. If is it possible please suggest me ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't go back to an older version. Update your app as needed and submit it as version 1.5.3 (or some other appropriate version number).

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking in your comment. You can't go back to version 1.5.1. You must submit version 1.5.3 (or later). If you want that version to be the same as version 1.5.1 then use your source code control system to roll back your code as needed. Then update the version to 1.5.3 and build and submit the update.